# 2 mouseover/hover effects in 1 div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I apologize in advance for poor English.

one item (price) should appear in the picture, and the other (desc) outside it. I am not able to get, there is only one.

I know that my code is wrong, but do not know how to bite it.

http://jsfiddle.net/USgE9/1/

```
<div class="grid_1">
<div class="projects view-first">
    <div class="tiptext"> <a href=""><img src="http://foto.scigacz.pl/cache/imgs/_w750/gallery/aktualnosci/imprezy/3ci_rajd_chlorowy/img_06.jpg" alt="'" width="235" height="133"/></a>

        <div class="description">Here is the big fat description box</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mask">
        <div class="info">  <span style="left:100px;position:absolute;">price: $200</span>

            <div class="button_add"><a href=""><img src="" alt="" style="float:right;right:20px;"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.description').hide();
    $('.tiptext').hover(function () {
        if (!$(this).children('.description').is(":animated")) {
            $(this).children('.description').fadeIn();
        }

    }, function () {
        $(this).children('.description').fadeOut();

    });
});
```

```css
.grid_1 {
    width: 235px;
}
.description {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:173px;
    height:133px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin:-138px 0 0 235px;
    color:#fff;
}
.mask .info {
    font-size:18px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    margin:4px 0 0 0;
}
.mask .info img {
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:-5px;
    padding:10px;
}
.projects {
    width: 235px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:133px;
    cursor: default;
}
.projects .mask {
    width: 235px;
    height: 33px;
    overflow:hidden;
    bottom: 0;
}
.view-first .mask {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(43, 45, 46, 0.9);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.view-first:hover .mask {
    opacity: 1;
}
.mask .info {
    font-size:18px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    margin:4px 0 0 0;
}
```

maybe someone is able to help me?

Comment: If I set the body background color to gray I can see the text with the price below the photo. Do you want it in the middle of the picture, is that the expected behavior? If it is, try adding a `top:100px` near the `left:100px;` it causes the price put in front of the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution

first your html should look like this

```
 <div class="grid_1">
    <div class="projects view-first">
        <div class="tiptext"> <a href=""><img src="http://foto.scigacz.pl/cache/imgs/_w750/gallery/aktualnosci/imprezy/3ci_rajd_chlorowy/img_06.jpg" alt="'" width="235" height="133"/></a>

            <div class="description">Here is the big fat description box</div>
        </div>


<div class="mask">
            <div class="info">  <span style="left:100px;position:absolute;">price: $200</span>

                <div class="button_add"><a href=""><img src="" alt="" style="float:right;right:20px;"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and you css should look like this

```
    .grid_1 {
    width: 235px;
}
.description {
    display:block;
 position:absolute;
    width:173px;
    height:133px;
    background-color:#000;
    left:235px;
    top:0;
    color:#fff;
}
.mask .info {
    font-size:18px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    margin:4px 0 0 0;
}
.mask .info img {
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:-5px;
    padding:10px;
}
.projects {
    width: 235px;
    height:133px;
    cursor: default;
    position:relative;
}
.projects .mask {
    width: 235px;
    height: 33px;
    overflow:hidden;
    bottom: 0;
    position:absolute;
}
.view-first .mask {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(43, 45, 46, 0.9);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.view-first:hover .mask {
    opacity: 1;
}
.mask .info {
    font-size:18px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    margin:4px 0 0 0;
}
```

please refer the updated http://jsfiddle.net/USgE9/5/

Comment: hey, it works perfectly, but what if I have the pictures side by side? may appear over the image? z-index?http://jsfiddle.net/USgE9/6/

Comment: ha! z-index:1 on .description, z-index:2 on img, works great, THX SO MUCH! :)

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple, You don't need javascript at all.

I also have simplified a lot of your markup and css.

http://jsfiddle.net/USgE9/4/

```
<a href="">
    <img src="http://foto.scigacz.pl/cache/imgs/_w750/gallery/aktualnosci/imprezy/3ci_rajd_chlorowy/img_06.jpg" alt="'" width="235" height="133"/>
    <div class="info">price: $200</div>
</a>
<div class="description">Here is the big fat description box</div>
```

This might be too much simplification for your particular case, but gives you a good clean starting point.